# Forging packet UDP with given TTL

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ip, ttl

I'd need build up an UDP packet with Python setting a particular value of its TTL. Could anyone show me the minimal-length code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [PyIP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyip/).

Not tested, but shows the idea:

```
import ip
import udp
import socket

# build UDP 
udp_packet = udp.Packet()
udp_packet.sport = 1024;
udp_packet.dport = 3024;
udp_packet.data = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFrcon \"test\" test\0"

udp_data = udp.assemble(udp_packet, 0)

# build IP packet
ip_packet = ip.Packet()
ip_packet.src = "1.1.1.1"
ip_packet.dst = "2.2.2.2"
ip_packet.ttl = 10
ip_packet.data = udp_data
packet = ip.assemble(ip_packet, 0)

# send the packet here
```